# User created forms for workout log app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a rails application that will allow users to let users create Workouts and Workout routines. Once The users have their workout routine they will be able to actually do the workout and log their progress. It will be very similar to Jefit.

I am new to rails and am having a hard time understanding how to go about how to create this app. How can I let the user generate their own forms to fill out later to log their workouts?

Comment: This is a very vague question. Try to be more specific and perhaps attempt to take *some* approach to building these dynamic forms before asking such a general question.

Answer (score 0):

From the brevity of your question it's hard to get a sense of whether you're asking about app architecture, about how rails works in general, or about the specifics of how to implement a dynamic form.

Unless you're trying to build some sort of complex javascript-based form design tool, which is ambitious if you're new to both rails and web development, I would suggest that the best starting place might be to design a template for a general form, or multiple templates of form components in rails partials, and then use the data that you collect when the user creates a workout to put the pieces together in a custom-ish form for them to use later.

This would, for example, allow a user to define a flexible number of exercises for a workout and then receive a workout-log form with a section for each exercise.